# Open default text editor from terminal

Tags: rhel, editors

Suppuse I have some text file and I want to open it with text editor, how to do that from terminal?.

1. I need it that it would work for Red hat 5.3 enterprise.
2. Without need to download nothing, I need the built in text editor.

I need something like: `[root@localhost]# open /home/Plompy/Desktop/README_PLOMPY`

That equivalent to this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Plompy.. Just type in terminal `gedit /home/Plompy/Desktop.README_PLOMPY` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Goro I am trying to edit `Plompy.h` file, I tried `gedit` now but it tells: `No protocol specified` and `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused` and `(gedit:12764): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:24:45.829: cannot open display: :0`, While I succeed to open it manually from text editor

Comment: Are you open it on a server? try `sudo gedit /home/Plompy/Desktop.README_PLOMPY` or `sudo nano /home/Plompy/Desktop.README_PLOMPY`

Comment: @Goro I installed ftp server, but I'm running Fedora right now

Comment: gedit is the official text editor of the GNOME desktop environment. Generally, in a server, there is no desktop environment installed or needed. Therefore, gedit can't start and display. I would suggest sudo nano /home/Plompy/Desktop.README_PLOMPY instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ubuntu exist a command called **xdg-open**, that opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application, so you can open several types of files with the default program pre-defined.

`xdg-open hello_word.tiff` Open the file using the default image visualizer.

`xdg-open Template.odt` Open the file using with LibreOffice.

`xdg-open myfile.txt` Open the file using gedit (Text editor).

By my knowledge the xdg-utils are already installed in Red hat.

Answer (score 1):

For the users who got here by Google search looking for a different answer, who want want to stay in the terminal: check to see if there's a defined editor, then try something else, like `nano file`, or use `xdg-open file` as a less portable fallback.

```
if [ -z ${EDITOR} ];  
then  
    xdg-open myfile.txt; #from Luis's answer above  
else  
    $EDITOR file.txt;  
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`xdg-open` only works when the file is a text-like file. To e.g. open an otherwise executable binary with a text editor instead, you can determine the default text editor for text files and run that on your file:

```bash
gtk-launch $(xdg-mime query default text/plain) your-file
```

Apparently there's a bug in XFCE though: This can potentially open another editor than the on the user has configured, see https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=68497#p68497